# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to-3}\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm going through my textbook, solving problems and am confused because the textbook seems to be giving me the incorrect answer. The question is:

$$ \lim_{x \to -3} \frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}$$

The way that I solved this was,

$$\frac{9-9}{...} = \frac{0}{...}$$

Which would end up being $0$, however the book gives me an answer of $6/5$

Comment: What value does $2x^2+7x+3$ have when $x=-3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Note that *both* the numerator and denominator evaluate to $0$ at $x = -3$. That means we have an indeterminate limit, which simply means more work needs to be done.

Factor numerator and denominator:

$$\frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3} = \dfrac{(x + 3)(x - 3)}{(x + 3)(2x + 1)}$$ Cancel the line terms.

$$\frac{(\cancel{x + 3})(x - 3)}{(\cancel{x + 3})(2x + 1)} = \frac{(x - 3)}{(2x +1)}$$

Now evaluate the limit of the right-hand side as $x\to -3$.

Comment: The important thing to know at this level of evaluating limits is that if the numerator is zero, you can only conclude the whole thing is zero **if** the denominator is **not** zero. We sometimes say $\frac00$ is indeterminate, because depending on how one gets to this symbolic expression $\frac00$, the actual limit may be any real number (or even$\pm\infty$).

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 2):

We may also use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).  Since $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}$$ is of indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, L'Hôpital's rule implies we differentiate the numerator and denominator to obtain $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{x^2-9}{2x^2+7x+3}=\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{2x}{4x+7}=\frac{6}{5}$$ since the right-most limit is not in indeterminate form.